# Snap cursor - wrong positioning with three vertices

Tags: snapping, 3d-cursor

Again, I have a quite strange problem: my cursor snaps to the wrong position when used with three vertices.

For testing purposes, I made an equilateral triangle:

[image: Erroneous snapping]

As on the third figure, when all three vertices are selected, and I use *Snap > Cursor to Selected*, the cursors snaps out of center. In all other cases, snapping is correct. It snaps to the middle of two vertices, and to the center of four vertices, and Blender correctly transforms the origin to the center of mass, if told to.

Even more strange: If I reload factory settings, the snapping works as intended. So there must be some mysterious setting saved with the blend file. There are no double vertices or zero faces. I'm at a complete lost here. Please advise.

[image]

Comment: I have the same .I looks like it snaps to the `bounding box center`. But I cant figure out why. What kind of plugins you have installed? Maybe one is overwriting it.

Comment: I disabled all mesh related addons, but that changed nothing. At the moment, I'm guessing it may happen, because the file was saved with an older blender version (2.78), and until now I upgraded to 2.79b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't let this go unanswered. It seems my problem is not a bug, but some kind of unintuitive feature.

First, I'm working with a disabled *3D Manipulator Widget*. Second, in most cases I'm modeling with circles or quads, and additionally with *Pivot Point Mode* set to *Individual Origins* or *Median Point*. So I simply never noticed that it's possible to snap the cursor to anything other than the average position of all selected vertices. Snapping them to the center of the bounding box does not make sense to me, but well, maybe it does for others.

So, the **Pivot Point Modes** *Active Element*, *3D Cursor* and *Bounding Box* will snap the cursor to the center of the bounding box, while the modes *Individual Origins* and *Median Point* will snap it to the average position of all selected vertices.

Answer (score 8):

It's stated pretty clearly [in the Blender manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/nb/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/snap.html#snap-menu), but if someone omits this source it'll be here:

> The *Cursor to Selected* option is also affected by the current [Pivot Point](https://docs.blender.org/manual/nb/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/pivot_point/index.html#pivot-point-index). For example:
>
> - With the *Bounding Box Center* pivot point active, the *Cursor to Selected* option will snap the 3D cursor to the center of the bounding
>     box surrounding the objects’ origins.
> - When the *Median Point* pivot point is selected, *Cursor to Selected* will snap the 3D cursor to the median of the object origins.

Comment: This _is_  quite counter intuitive.. and not something I've ever reached for the manual to find out. It's handy to know,

Comment: It says about Bounding Box (BB), but doesn't explain why 3D Cursor pivot mode acts like BB as default and not like Median, which is strange.

Comment: As you can see in my screenshot, the pivot point is set to 3D cursor. And as I wrote: the strange behavior is in an older file, but if I use factory setting, all works as usual. In my file, ONLY pivot mode "Median Point" gets the desired result. Added blend file in question.

Comment: @Grimm I only see the expected behavior with 2.79, even in your .blend. With the pivot point set to *Median*, the cursor goes to the average of the positions of the selected vertices.

Comment: @gandalf3 And if you set pivot point to *3D Cursor*? In this case, it snaps to Bounding Box center, instead of average position. The default should always be *average*, if not *Bounding Box* is selected, but in this file it's not. Guess it's just a bug.

Comment: Where does it say the default behavior should be median? For me it always uses bounding box unless the pivot is set to median, in any file I've tried.

Comment: I don't see why a  _transformation_ origin ( a pivot point) should have anything whatsoever to do with a snap target. They are different things. Whether it is or not, handing the responsibility over to the pivot point setting, instead of having a 'Bounding Box' option in the snap, looks like a fudge.

Comment: @RobinBetts Perhaps I'm in the minority here, but I don't find using the pivot point unintuitive? The snapping operators are still transformations. I think I would find it harder to keep track of two separate pivot points than just have one global one I can change quickly. If there were a case where you might want to use two different pivots at the same time, I could see it, but I can't currently imagine how such a situation might arise.

Comment: @gandalf3 1. [IANW](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c3sOuEv0E2I). 2. If I _do_  consider the snap to be a transformation of the cursor, respecting the global pivot-point, then I would have to think of it as a scale to 0 about that point? Mentally framing it that way works for 'Median',and 'Bounding Box', but it doesn't work for 'Active'....  '3D Cursor' and 'Individual Origins' become null default behaviors .. I don't know... maybe I'm getting the wrong end of your stick.

Comment: @RobinBetts I'm completely with you in this matter. It's unintuitive that the pivot point is considered at all. I did not expect this, but well, since I know it, I can live with it. Never stop learning.   :)